# Embedding audio/video in showoff presentations

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Has anyone figured out a good way to embed video and audio into [showoff](https://github.com/schacon/showoff) presentations? Currently I am just putting video on youtube and linking to it like this in the slide:

```
!SLIDE full-page

# My Video
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="410"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I was wondering if anyone had a better/more efficient way of putting in video and/or audio.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can host it yourself and try to leverage the browser's capabilities. Here's an approach:

```
<video controls width="360" height="240" poster="placeholder.jpg">
  <source src="movie.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="360" height="240" data="player.swf?file=movie.mp4">
    <embed flashvars="file=movie.mp4"
           allowfullscreen="true"
           allowscriptaccess="always"
           id="player1"
           name="player1"
           src="player.swf"
           width="480"
           height="270"
    />
    <p>You need Flash or a modern browser to view this video</p>
  </object>
</video>
```

It will try leveraging HTML5's video tag on browsers that support ogg or mp4. If that fails, it tries using flash (I used JW Player for this example, but it could be any other one). If all fails, it tells the viewer it needs flash or a modern browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have actually quit using Showoff for this reason and switched to just creating html5 slideshows since it seems much more flexible. I wanted something easy, since like others, I upload my presentations to heroku.

Comment: I've been trying something like this but the video files are not able to be found. I stripped it down to this:

`<video id="sampleMovie" src="CNN-issues.ogv" width="900px" controls="true" autoplay="true" type="video/ogv" ></video>`

and I keep seeing "Video format or MIME type is not supported."  When I right click and choose "View Video" or "Copy Video Location" neither link works. I've tried relative paths to the video, as well as one coming from ~/home. I'm wondering if this has something to do with localhost/sinatra stuff. It's a little over my head. Any help?

Comment: [According to the developer](https://github.com/puppetlabs/showoff/issues/179), you need to add file to the src, like so: `<video id="sampleMovie" src="file/CNN-issues.ogv" width="900px" controls="true" autoplay="true" type="video/ogv" ></video>` Though this will change in future releases (see link).